# Call Laravel model by string

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.1

Is it possible to call a Laravel model by string?

This is what i'm trying to achieve but its failing:

```
$model_name = 'User';
$model_name::where('id', $id)->first();
```

I get the following exception:

```
exception 'ErrorException' with message 'Undefined variable: User'
```

Comment: try using the full namespace like `$model_name = 'App\Http\Model\User';`

Comment: That worked but im actually trying to do it from an instance variable and thats still failing: `${$this->model_name}::where`

Comment: can you describe your comment please?

Comment: Of course its also possible to `app($model_name)->where(....)`

Answer (score 75, accepted):

Yes, you can do this, but you need to use the fully qualified class name:

```
$model_name = 'App\Model\User';
$model_name::where('id', $id)->first();
```

If your model name is stored in something other than a plain variable (e.g. a object attribute), you will need to use an intermediate variable in order to get this to work.

```
$model = $this->model_name;
$model::where('id', $id)->first();
```

Answer (score 31):

Try this:

```
$model_name = 'User';
$model = app("App\Model\{$model_name}");
$model->where('id', $id)->first();
```

Comment: Can you explain why you used app() ? Thanks in advance

Comment: @RajaKhoury to get instance, or in other words "return var_dump( app('App\User') );" and see result

Comment: I had to escape the trailing backslash with another backslash: `$modelPath = "App\Models\\{$modelName}";`

Comment: This was exactly what I needed, next time all you have to do is give a detailed description of exactly what your code is expected to do, some of us run code in our heads before we start typing.

Answer (score 2):

This method should work well:

```
private function getNamespace($model){
    $dirs = glob('../app/Models/*/*');

    return array_map(function ($dir) use ($model) {
        if (strpos($dir, $model)) {
            return ucfirst(str_replace(
                '/',
                '\\',
                str_replace(['../', '.php'], '', $dir)
            ));
        }
    }, array_filter($dirs, function ($dir) use ($model) {
        return strpos($dir, $model);
    }));
}
```

My project has multiple subdirectory and this function work well. So I recover the namespace of the model with `$model = current($this->getNamespace($this->request->get('model')));` 
Then I just have to call my query: `$model::all()`

Answer (score 1):

if you use it in many of the places use this function

```
function convertVariableToModelName($modelName='',$nameSpace='App')
        {
            if (empty($nameSpace) || is_null($nameSpace) || $nameSpace === "") 
            {                
               $modelNameWithNameSpace = "App".'\\'.$modelName;
                return app($modelNameWithNameSpace);    
            }

            if (is_array($nameSpace)) 
            {
                $nameSpace = implode('\\', $nameSpace);
                $modelNameWithNameSpace = $nameSpace.'\\'.$modelName;
                return app($modelNameWithNameSpace);    
            }elseif (!is_array($nameSpace)) 
            {
                $modelNameWithNameSpace = $nameSpace.'\\'.$modelName;
                return app($modelNameWithNameSpace);    
            }
        }
```

Example if you want to get all the user

**Scenario 1:**

```
 $userModel= convertVariableToModelName('User');
  $result = $userModel::all();
```

**Scenario 2:**

if your model in in custom namespace may be `App\Models`

```
$userModel= convertVariableToModelName('User',['App','Models']);
$result = $userModel::all();
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do it with more flexible way. Create a common function.

```
function getWhere($yourModel, $select, $is_model_full_path=null, $condition_arr=null)
{
    if(!$is_model_full_path){ // if your model exist in App directory
        $yourModel ="App\\$yourModel";
    }
    if(!$condition_arr){
        return $yourModel::all($select)->toArray();
    }
    return $App_models_yourModel::all($select)->where($condition_arr)->toArray();
}
```

Now you can call this method in different ways.

```
getWhere('User', ['id', 'name']); // with default path of model
getWhere('App\Models\User', ['id', 'name'], true); // with custom path of model
getWhere('User', ['id', 'name'], false, ['id', 1]); // with condition array
```

By the way I like to use such functions.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try like this:-

```
use App\Model\User;

class UsersController extends Controller
{

 protected $model;

 public function __construct(User $model)
 {
    $this->model = $model;
 }

 public function getUser()
 {
  $data = $this->model->where('id', $id)->first();

  return $data;
 }

}
```