# Call laravel model dynamically

Tags: php, laravel, model, call, laravel-5.5

I am trying to call a Model dynamically, but I am getting ..

```
Class 'xxx' not found
```

Here's my code:

```
use App\xxx;
.
.
.

$model = ucfirst(explode('_', $title)[0]);
$model::where('name', 'john')->get()->toArray();
```

dd($model) gives:

```
"xxx"
```

Comment: try `dd($model)`

Comment: @Sohel0415, updated my answer.

Comment: Why? I can’t really think of a good reason to call a Laravel model dynamically like this.

Comment: @MartinBean, I am trying to insert into some tables from excel file, and if followed the static approach, it will be headache.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34409665/call-laravel-model-by-string

Comment: as @Amarnasan said, try with full path

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If `$xxx` is not full class name, do this:

```
$model = 'App\\' . $model;
$model::where('name', 'john')->get()->toArray();
```

Comment: I can't remove this part, it's everything, It's the dynamic itself.

Comment: @CairoCoder why can't you move this part? Please give an example of real data and model class names. This approach will only work if you'll use the real full class' name.

Comment: Your last edit is perfect, second part helped me out :)